# Como puedo hacer que mi switch(on/off) aparezca como encendido automáticamente sin darle click, al seleccionar una opción de un combo de otro campo?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer que mi switch(on/off) aparezca como encendido automaticamente sin darle click, al seleccionar una opcion de un combo? en js

Comment: Hola amigo, estamos contentos de tenerte por aquí. Pero para que puedan ayudarte, quiza deberias de revisar la dumentación de [como se hace una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) debes añadir detalles de lo que has hecho y cual son tus problemas. Del modo que lo presentas, quieres que te den una respuestas. Aquí te ayudaran con un problema o duda. Por otro lado, si esperas que te hagan el trabajo, nunca aprenderas. Por supuesto eres libre de hacer lo que gustes, pero si no modificas tu pregunta, nadie te ayiudara.

Comment: Hola amigo, estamos contentos de tenerte por aquí. Pero para que puedan ayudarte, quiza deberias de revisar la dumentación de como se hace una pregunta debes añadir detalles de lo que has hecho y cual son tus problemas. Del modo que lo presentas, quieres que te den una respuestas. Aquí te ayudaran con un problema o duda. Por otro lado, si esperas que te hagan el trabajo, nunca aprenderas. Por supuesto eres libre de hacer lo que gustes, pero si no modificas tu pregunta, nadie te ayudara.